# Namespaces for "Magento\\Framework\\", "Magento\\" and physical directory structure

Tags: composer, vendor

I have a custom class
 `'class ProductsList extends\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList'` 
and wonder where is the physical file containing the class?

Looking at the top level composer file, I see

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    }
```

... but when I look in the 'lib/internal' directory, there's no 'Magento/Framework'. Same goes for "Magento\": "app/code/Magento/"

What I do see in the project directory structure is 'vendor/magento/framework'

I looked at the project structure of Magento in GitHub at https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework and there's the directory mapping I expected.

I'm trying to make sense of what I think the composer file is telling me and why the physical directory structure is not what I expect it to be.

PS: new to both php and Magento

Comment: It will be in your vendor folder @vector. You will find all magento module under magento folder. Here is your framework path : \vendor\magento\framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ProductsList extends\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
```

this would tell you exactly where it lies.

class **ProductList** - File **ProductList.php** in your custom module placed at **app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/Block**

extends **\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList** - this particular class can be found in a file placed at **vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductList.php**